# Turn off Mandrill transactional email URL tracking

Tags: url-rewriting, mailchimp, mandrill

I use simple SMTP settings to send emails from my app with Mandrill. Mandrill however hijacks the links and injects its own URLs so that link is rerouted via their servers. That results with user seeing the mandrill URL in their browser before going to the the right page. Any way to turn that off?

I looked through the settings and could not find it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's an option on the [Sending Defaults](https://mandrillapp.com/settings/sending-options) page in your account that is for click-tracking (should be a drop down menu, near the top, just below the checkbox for tracking opens). What you select there will be the default option applied to all messages, unless you provide a different per-message setting for click-tracking. With SMTP, you can set click-tracking on a per-message basis using custom SMTP headers. More information about using SMTP headers to customize this can be found in the [Mandrill KB here](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21688056-Using-SMTP-Headers-to-customize-your-messages#enable-open-and-click-tracking).

Comment: So quick answer is to add the SMTP header `X-MC-Track: none`. The header's value can be anything not specified as a tracking behavior, so I chose `none` and it works.
https://mailchimp.com/developer/transactional/docs/smtp-integration/#x-mc-track

Answer (score 18):

Also it's simple to disable click-tracking for individual link by **mc:disable-tracking** parameter.

```
<a href="//example.com" mc:disable-tracking>
  Click here to confirm your email
</a>
```

The extra parameter will be removed when the email is sent, and no click-tracking will be applied to this link.

See: [documentation](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582927-Can-I-disable-click-tracking-on-selected-links-in-my-email-).